# Passing parent class initialized variables to an instance of a child class

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance, parent-child

(working in Ruby)
First off, I apologize in advance.  I'm not a programmer by training, I've simply come to it by dint of convenience and a changing world.  What I needed to do involved programming, and I got tired of waiting around for others to do my programming for me.  As such, I've missed some basic concepts along the way, and when I ask these questions I sometimes make a fool of myself by consequence.

Let's say I want to define a species/job relationship in classes.  I want to define a superclass "BlackAnt" and have subclasses "Worker" "Fighter" and "Queen"

To me, intuitively, this looks something like this:

```
class BlackAnt
  @legs = 6
end

class Worker < BlackAnt
  @jaws = 'small'
end
```

but if I then try

```
ant1 = Worker.new
puts ant1.legs
```

I get an error.  If I amend class BlackAnt to:

```
class BlackAnt
  attr_accessor :legs
  @legs = 6
end
```

ant1.legs returns 'nil'

I've tried the method outlined here: http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/

and this allows Worker.legs to return '6', but... alas:

```
ant1 = Worker.new
Worker.legs => '6'
ant1.legs => 'nil'
```

At a guess, the values of those parent variables are not being initialized each time a new child is spawned.

I feel I'm being silly about this somehow, and the reply is no doubt going to make me curse the day I discovered caffeine-driven all-nighters.  What I need to do is arrange things so that I can create objects like so:

```
ant1 = Worker.new
ant2 = Queen.new
ant3 = Fighter.new
```

and have them each acquire the appropriate quantity of legs, along with whatever special characteristics were assigned in the child class.  The worker/queen/fighter classifications will be bound by namespaces such that the actual calls will be:

```
ant1 = AntBlack::Worker.new
ant2 = AntRed::Worker.new
ant3 = AntRed::Queen.new
```

etc.

I'd like to then be able to check the quantity of legs of an individual ant using:

```
ant1.legs #=> 6
```

I may be going around my elbow to get to my thumb.  If so, feel free to offer alternate suggestions for ways to achieve the same result, I will greatly appreciate the insights.

///updated re:response///

```
class AntRed
  attr_accessor :legs
  def initialize
    @legs = 6
  end
end

class Worker < AntRed
  @strength = 1
end
```

result:

```
irb(main):009:0> ant1 = Worker.new
#=> #<Worker:0x87616ac @strength=1>
irb(main):010:0> ant1.legs
#=> nil
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define your BlackAnt class as follows:

```
class BlackAnt
  attr_accessor :legs

  def initialize
    @legs = 6
  end
end
```

And your Worker class as follows:

```
class Worker < BlackAnt
  attr_accessor :strength

  def initialize
    super

    @strength = 1
  end
end
```

The way you currently define the BlackAnt class, you are storing legs as a [class level instance variable](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply - This does not, however, seem to be the resolution.  Can't put code blocks in here so I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: If you added an initialize method to your Worker class as well, you need to remember to call super.  I edited my answer to show you what I mean in case that is the problem.

Comment: Right, it's working now, both uninitialized and initialized.  I'm too tired to wonder why the uninitialized version wasn't working before (five bucks on "I forgot to hit ctrl+s before I reloaded it"), so I'll just thank you profusely and fall asleep like a drunken hippo.

Answer (score 0):

> At a guess, the values of those parent variables are not being
>   initialized each time a new child is spawned.

In Ruby instance variables belong to a single object. Look at point 7) in my answer starting

> To address your "If true that they are variables"

in [Why are symbols in Ruby not thought of as a type of variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850971/why-are-symbols-in-ruby-not-thought-of-as-a-type-of-variable/13861177#13861177)

I don't understand why you get `irb(main):010:0> ant1.legs #=> nil`. For me it works (at least as script).

```
class AntRed
  attr_accessor :legs
  def initialize
    @legs = 6
  end
end

class Worker < AntRed
end

ant1 = Worker.new
print 'ant1.legs : '; puts ant1.legs
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w test.rb 
ant1.legs : 6
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean you want a class's instance varieble which has been initialed!

so you can do it like this:

```
class BlackAnt
  attr_accessor :legs
  @legs = 6

  def initialize
    @legs = self.class.instance_variable_get(:@legs)
  end
end

newObj = BlackAnt.new
newObj.legs
```

Comment: It's a ugly method, I think