# What is the difference between local, instance, and class variables?

Tags: ruby, instance-variables, local-variables, class-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between class variables and class instance variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802540/difference-between-class-variables-and-class-instance-variables)

While reading a Ruby book, I seem to have missed the variables chapter. Now I can't seem to understand the following things:

1. What is an instance variable?
2. What is a class instance variable?
3. What is the difference between a `variable`, `@instance_var` and `@class_instance_var`?

I tried to read some posts in different blogs, but I still do not understand.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you read an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802540/difference-between-class-variables-and-class-instance-variables ?

Comment: 1) A @@cv is a class variable, not a class instance variable. A @class_inst_var is an instance variable defined in the body of a class, considered as instance of Class, and outside method definitions. 2) The belief that an instance variable has a value for each instance comes from static languages. In Ruby, a variable does not exist until you assign a value to it. Please read the demonstration here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850971/why-are-symbols-in-ruby-not-thought-of-as-a-type-of-variable/13861177#13861177

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is an instance variable?

It's a variable that has an idependant value that pertains to this instance of a class. For example, a `Person` class could have `@name` and `@age` as instance variables. All instance of `Person` have a name and age, but each instance will have a different value for those things.

---

> What is a class instance variable?

This is a little wierd, but you have to realize that the `Person` class is itself an instance of `Class`.  So it too can have instance variables. This is often used to configure a class. Like perhaps to add an API key to a class so that all instance can be created with that data.

```
class PersonFetcher

  # class method can set class instance variables
  def self.set_api_key(key)
    @api_key = key
  end

  # instance method sets instance variables
  def set_name(name)
    @name = name
  end

end
```

---

> What is the difference between a variable, @instance_var and @class_instance_var?

How it persists.

`variable` is local. It's simply a reference to an object. Once no code or object has a reference to this value it is destroyed via garbage collection. It only persists if you keep using it.

`@instance_var` persists on an instance. So long as the instance persists, the instance variables it has will as well. So long as the `Person` instance exists, that instance will have a `@name`.

`@class_instance_var` persists on the class object (which remember is an instance of `Class`). So it will exist in the class object forever, since you can never really get rid of declared classes.

Answer (score 4):

### Variable Type Affects Scope

There are many canonical explanations on the web, and some in-depth explanations elsewhere on SO, but I'll share with you another way of looking at it: variable scope.

#### Local Variables

A local variable is typically used in a method, and has only local scope. For example:

```
def foo
  # bar is only in scope within #foo.
  bar = true
end
```

The *bar* variable goes out of scope whenever the method returns.

#### Instance Variables

Instance variables are available to any method bound to an object instance. As a practical matter, this generally gives it scope within some instantiated class object. For example:

```
class Foo
  def bar
    @quux = true
  end

  def baz
    @quux == true
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
```

While @quux isn't truly global, it is visible to all methods bound to our instantiated *foo* object without the need to pass it around explicitly as a parameter.

#### Class Variables

Class variables are shared among all instances of a class. That means that if you change @@bar from instance foo, then the value is also changed for instance bar.

```
class Foo
  @@bar = true

  def show_class_variable
    @@bar
  end

  def bar= value
    @@bar = value
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
bar = Foo.new

foo.show_class_variable # => true
bar.show_class_variable # => true

foo.bar = false
foo.show_class_variable # => false
bar.show_class_variable # => false
```

Note how changing @@bar affected both instances simultaneously. That's the beauty (and the horror) of class variables.

Answer (score 1):

A varaible is something local to a method and thus should be defined in this method, an instance variable is a variable that is defined for (instance of) an object of the given class and has a value for **each** object. A class instance variable is denoted with `@@`(as opposed to the single `@` you mention) and is shared between **all** instances of a class and if one of them changes its value then all the instances will see the new value. A class instance variable is equivelent to c++ and java's static member variables and the instance variables are equivelent to the non-static ones.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but there are 2 types of @var

Comment: @sannySin afaik there is only one

Comment: 1) A @@cv is a class variable, not a class instance variable. A @class_inst_var is an instance variable defined in the body of a class, considered as instance of Class, and outside method definitions. 2) The belief that an instance variable has a value for each instance comes from static languages. In Ruby, a variable does not exist until you assign a value to it. Please read the demonstration here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850971/why-are-symbols-in-ruby-not-thought-of-as-a-type-of-variable/13861177#13861177

Answer (score 1):

Instance variables are defined at the moment when a class has been instaniated. Suppose you have a class `Point`, which define some local variables and methods.

```
class Point
  def initialize(x,y)
     @x, @y = x, y
  end

  def add(other)
     Point.new(@x + other, @y + other)
  end
end
```

When you instantiate the defined class and assign it to a variable you are instantiating the class:

```
point = Point.new(2,2)
```

..this is the instance variable.

Classes in Ruby are Objects and can have instance variables as other objects can. An instance variable defined inside a `class` definition, but outside an instance method definition is called **class instance variable**.

Example:

```
class Point 
  @n = 0
  @total_x = 0
  @total_y = 0

  def initialize(x,y)
     @x,@y = x,y
  end
end
```

There is a third one, namely the `class variable`. Class variables are visible to, and shared by the class methods and the instance methods of the class. Like instance variables, class variables can be used by the implementation of a class, but they are not visible to the users of the class. Class variables begin with `@@`. Instance variables are always evaluated in reference to `self`. This is a significant difference from class variables, which are always evaluated in reference to the class object created by the enclosing `class` definition statement. Using the same example we can rewrite the code as follows:

```
class Point
   @@n = 0
   @@total_x = 0
   @@total_y = 0

   def initialize(x,y)
      @x,@y = x, y
      @@n += 1
   end

   def self.report
      puts "Number of points: #{@@n.to_s}"
   end
end
```

Comment: Instance variables do not necessary have to be defined at the moment a class has been instantiated. It could be defined after a class has been instantiated as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could find alot of articles in regards with a simple google search:

http://blog.codegram.com/2011/4/understanding-class-instance-variables-in-ruby

http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/