# Syntax differences between method calls and variable calls in embedded ruby scripts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

This might be a noob question but here it goes:
I'm trying to parse embbeded ruby code and I need some help in understanding the synthax for methodcalls and variable accesing in embedded ruby scripts. 
For example in this call `@user.followed_users.count` (as I understand it) @user is an instance of a the user model followed_users is a (automatically generated) method and count is also a method right? 
But what are these calls `micropost.content` `micropost.created_at` `micropost.user`? They are from this erb file:

```
<li>
  <span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
  <% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", micropost, method: :delete,
                                     data:{ confirm: "You sure?" },
                                     title: micropost.content %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

(these are code examples from this michael hartl rails tutorial)

What kinds of syntaxes for method calls and variable accessing from erb files are there in Rails? Is it possible to access variables from ruby files that are not instance or class variables?

Thanks in advance for reading and helping :)

Comment: What is a synthax?

Comment: @sawa sorry senpai

Answer (score 1):

### The syntax is the same.

There are no major syntactical differences between ERB and Ruby except that ERB is an embedded language where only the code in "erb" tags are executed `<% %>`.

### Whats the difference between a local variable and a method?

A method is a method object that is defined on an object.

```
def foo
  "hello world"
end

# we can call it by
self.foo

# we can access the method object by
self.method(:foo)
```

This defines the method `foo` on `main`.

```
bar = "value"
```

Defines the locally scoped variable `bar`. Not that you can't do `self.bar` since it just points to a memory register, not a method! You don't call variables - you reference them*. Thus the term "variable call" is just wrong.

As @SergioTulentsev points out you can check if a `micropost` is a local variable or method by using `defined?`. Note the caveat when using *rails locals* below.

See:

- [What is the difference between local, instance, and class variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127805/what-is-the-difference-between-local-instance-and-class-variables)

### Using ERB outside of rails

In Ruby the top level object is called `main` which is the "global" object.
When you assign a instance variable `<% @foo = "bar" %>` you are assigning it to `main` which is the implicit self.

```
<%# raw_template.erb %>
<%= self.inspect %>
```

If we run `erb raw_template.erb` it will output `main`.

Assigning a regular lexical variable (a local) `<% foo = "bar" %>` works just like in any other ruby code.

As you can see is no difference in how variables work in an ERB template and any other Ruby code.

### What does rails do differently?

A core piece of Rails is what is called the *view context*. This is an instance of `ActionView::Base` which is the implicit self - the "global" object.

You don't have to take my word for it. Try including this in a view in Rails:

```
<pre>
  <%= self.inspect %>
</pre>
```

Rails takes all the instance variables of the controller and assigns them to the view context. Which why the `@something` instance variable you assign in your controller is also available to your views.

### [Rails locals](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html#partials) are not really local variables

The view context also contains a hash called `local_assigns`. These are the "local variables" you can pass when rendering a template:

```
render template: 'test', locals: { foo: 'bar' }
```

When you call `<%= foo %>` in the `test.html.erb` template the call goes to [`method_missing`](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_method_missing.html) which checks if `local_assigns` has a `:foo` key.

Thats why using `defined?` on `local_assigns` variables does not work as expected.

### But the syntax is the same.

Rails uses a bit of metaprogramming magic to pass variables around - but it does not alter the syntax of the language.

> Is it possible to access variables from ruby files that are not
>   instance or class variables?

Yes, global variables - in Ruby you create a global variable by using the sigil `$`.

```
$foo = "bar"
```

But this is rarely used because [globals are evil](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad). And there are better ways to it in Ruby.

Comment: * yes you can call a local variable if it happens to be a callable type like a Proc. But you're actually just referencing an object and calling its `.call` method.

Answer (score 0):

`micropost` in `<%= micropost.content %>` can be a local variable OR a method. There's no way to tell which is it, just by looking at the line. All that matters is `micropost` evaluates to *something* you can call `.content` on.

If you want to know which is it (for education), you can output its type like this:

```
<%= defined?(micropost) %>
```

It'll return either "local-variable" or "method" (or nil, if it's not defined).

Comment: Thank you @SergioTulentsev . what exactly is micropost then in this call, is it a variable?

Comment: @pokeahontas Did you read my post? It's impossible to __know__ (one can make educated guesses, though).

Comment: and if I'm calling a method declared in a ruby file(from controller/helper/model) is there anyway to recognize this synthactically in the erb file?

Comment: if it accepts parameters (`foo 1, 2`), then `foo` obviously can't be a variable. For parameterless (and parenthesis-less) calls, there's no way.