# How does Inheritance work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance, metaclass, eigenclass

According to Dave Thomas in [his talk about the Ruby Object Model](http://scotland-on-rails.s3.amazonaws.com/2A04_DaveThomas-SOR.mp4), there are no "class methods" in Ruby. There is only difference between whether the receiver of the method is a "class object" or an "instance object".

```
class Dave
  def InstaceMethod              ### will be stored in the current class (Dave)
    puts "Hi"
  end
  class << self                  ### Creates an eigenclass, if not created before
    def say_hello
      puts "Hello"
    end
  end
end
```

By default, `ancestors` method doesn't show the metaclass:

```
class Dave
  class << self
    def metaclass                ### A way to show the hidden eigenclass
      class << self; self; end
    end
  end
end

p Dave.ancestors
# => [Dave, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
p Dave.metaclass.ancestors
# => [Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

However, I assume the real one would be something like:

```
# => [<eigenclass>, Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

p Dave.class.instance_method(false)
# => [:allocate, :new, :superclass]
p Dave.metaclass.instance_method(false)
# => [:say_hello, :metaclass]
```

Now the inheritence.

```
class B < Dave
end

p B.say_hello
# => "Hello"
p B.ancestors
# => [B, Dave, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
p B.class.instance_methods(false)
# => [:allocate, :new, :superclass]
```

The following would create a new eigenclass for `B`:

```
p B.metaclass.ancestors
# => [Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
p B.metaclass.instance_method(false)
# => []
```

1. How would the `B.ancestors` and `B.metaclass.ancestors` look like when the eigenclasses are also included? The method `say_hello` is stored in an eigenclass, (which I assume `B.class` inherits from) but where is that?
2. Since there are two ancestor chains (`B.ancestors` and `B.class.ancestors` or `B.metaclass.ancestors`), how does the inheritance actually take place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eigenclass is a sneaky hidden one. You have successfully revealed it by opening class. But it does not exist in the ancestors of normal class. And since it is **hidden**, you cannot see it by sending `ancestors` method to a eigenclass itself. The inheritance tree is like the following:

```
B ---S-->  Dave   ---S---> Object  ---S---> BasicObject
|            |               |                  |
E            E               E                  E
|            |               |                  |
#B --S--> #Dave   ---S---> #Object ---S---> #BasicObject --S---> Class,,Object,BasicObject
```

`S` stands for superclass, while `E` for eigenclass.

Answer (score 3):

An object (and also a class which is an object, instance of Class) has a class field which points to its class. Creating a singleton class (eigenclass/metaclass) creates an anonymous class and changes this pointer to point to the anonymous class, whose class pointer will point to the original class. The `class` method does not display the anonymous class, only the original class. The same for mixins. A class has a superclass field. The method `include` creates an anonymous proxy, the superclass pointer is changed to point to the anonymous proxy class, and from there to the superclass. The method `ancestors` does not show the anonymous class, but the name of the included module. The `superclass` method does not display the anonymous proxy class, only the original superclass.

You can read this : [Why are symbols in Ruby not thought of as a type of variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850971/why-are-symbols-in-ruby-not-thought-of-as-a-type-of-variable/13871724#13871724)

In a comment to this answer, there is a link to an interesting article on singleton class that can be found on a Devalot blog.

One needs some time to assimilate these inheritance chains. As a good picture is worth a long explanation, I recommend chapter 24 Metaprogramming in [The Pickaxe](https://pragprog.com/titles/ruby4/programming-ruby-1-9-2-0-4th-edition/) which has various pictures about all these chains.

> By default, ancestors method doesn't show the metaclass:
> and 1. How would the B.ancestors ... look like when the eigenclasses are also included?

`ancestors` concerns the superclass chain. The eigenclass does not belong to the superclass chain.

> p Dave.metaclass.ancestors
> => [Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
> However, I assume the real one would be something like:
> => [*"eigenclass"*, Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

Correct.

You can simplify your Dave class :

```
class Dave
    def self.say_hello    # another way to create an eigenclass, if not created before
      puts "Hello"
    end
    def self.metaclass    # A way to show the hidden eigenclass
        class << self
            self
        end
    end
end

Dave.say_hello           # => Hello
Dave.new.class.say_hello # => Hello
p Dave.metaclass.instance_methods(false) # => [:say_hello, :metaclass]
p Dave.singleton_methods                 # => [:say_hello, :metaclass]
```

`def self.metaclass` is superfluous since Ruby 1.9.2, which has introduced `Object#singleton_class`.