# Instance variables in a Ruby Class object

Tags: ruby

Given the Ruby code below, can someone help me understand the different use cases between `@v` and `@@w`?  I understand that the class `C` is an object of the class `Class`, and because of this, `@v` is an instance variable of the class `C` object.

```
class C
  @v = "I'm an instance variable of the class C object."
  puts @v

  @@w = "I'm a class variable of the class C."
  puts @@w
end
```

Comment: http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/ just use google, there are A LOT of links explaining the differences and use cases

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850971/why-are-symbols-in-ruby-not-thought-of-as-a-type-of-variable/13861177#13861177

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance Variable's scope is just limited to the object of the Class. For eg. If you intantiate the Class C by creating an object then you have the access to @v.

Where as The Class Variables span through out the class i.e. they are also visible to the instances of the Classes(ie Objects) and other class methods.

**Related Reading:**

[Difference between class variables and class instance variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802540/difference-between-class-variables-and-class-instance-variables)

http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/

Comment: thanks for the insights! this makes a lot more sense now

Answer (score 1):

Instance variables are used each time an object is created and if they are unintialized, they have a `nil` value, and  class variables need to be initialized, and if they aren't, they produce and error.

One of the biggest reasons is sub-classing. If you plan on sub-classing you would want to use class variables. Here is a link that talks about the two and when to use what:

http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/

Here is a link that should help describe the difference between the two:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_variables.htm

Here is some code from the site I just mentioned that shows both being used:

```
    #!/usr/bin/ruby

class Customer
   @@no_of_customers=0
   def initialize(id, name, addr)
      @cust_id=id
      @cust_name=name
      @cust_addr=addr
   end
   def display_details()
      puts "Customer id #@cust_id"
      puts "Customer name #@cust_name"
      puts "Customer address #@cust_addr"
    end
    def total_no_of_customers()
       @@no_of_customers += 1
       puts "Total number of customers: #@@no_of_customers"
    end
end

# Create Objects
cust1=Customer.new("1", "John", "Wisdom Apartments, Ludhiya")
cust2=Customer.new("2", "Poul", "New Empire road, Khandala")

# Call Methods
cust1.total_no_of_customers()
cust2.total_no_of_customers()
```