# Instance variables in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
 class Sample
   attr_accessor :x,:y

   def initialize 
     @x = "x"
     y = "y"     
   end
 end     

 Sample.new.instance_variables  => [:@x] 

class Sample
  attr_accessor :x,:y

  def initialize 
     @x = "x"
     self.y = "y"     
  end
end  

Sample.new.instance_variables => [:@x, :@y]
```

Can anyone let me know what is going on here. Why is y an instance_variable second time?

Comment: In first sample, if you assign : `@y=1` , then you shall get `@y` as ivar as well. I surmise Ruby is optimizing in the `attr_accessor`, and not creating an ivar until you specifically assign to it.

Comment: and @Zabba : A variable does not exist until you assign a value to it. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850971/why-are-symbols-in-ruby-not-thought-of-as-a-type-of-variable/13861177#13861177

Answer (score 8):

`attr_accessor :y` defines methods that are roughly equivalent to

```
def y
  @y
end

def y=(val)
  @y = val
end
```

So, when you assign to `self.y`, you are assigning to an instance variable due to the `attr_accessor` macro

Comment: Careful with the terminology. `self.y = 1` is **not** an assignment to ivar

Comment: "assigning to an instance variable _due to the_ ...". I thought that made it clear that macro was why you had the ivar, not the assignment :|

Answer (score 1):

Why not? `self` is an instance and `y` is an instance var. In the first example, `y` is only a  normal local var.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
attr_accessor :y
```

creates a couple of methods

```
def y
  @y
end

def y= val
  @y = val
end
```

So, when you call `y=` method, `@y` instance variable jumps to life. In second snippet you correctly call `y=` method. But in the first one you simply create an unused local variable `y` (setter method is not called and ivar is not created).

Comment: It's important to note that historically `attr_accessor` will benchmark faster than these equivalent methods, they're C-based optimizations instead of executable code, so whenever possible you should use the `attr_` declarations instead of writing your own.