# Defining singleton methods

Tags: ruby, singleton-methods

The following code is from the book *Exceptional Ruby*:

```
starts_with_a = Object.new

def starts_with_a. ===(e)
    /^A/ =~ e.name
end
```

If I comment out the first line where a new object is assigned to `starts_with_a`, then I get this error:

```
`<main>': undefined local variable or method `starts_with_a' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Question 1: why do I need to assign a new object to `starts_with_a` to avoid that error?

Also, the method definition `starts_with_a` has a `.` before the `===`, although the variable `starts_with_a` does not. There's an error if I leave out that `.` in the method definition.

Question 2: what is happening with that `.`? why is it necessary etc.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706373/what-does-def-self-function-name-mean/13709911#13709911

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `def starts_with_a. ===(e)`, you are defining a singleton method `===` on the object `starts_with_a`. The `.` between the object and the method indicates that it is a method defined on that object. If you do not have such object already created, a singleton method cannot be defined on it, and will return an error.